# Rvalue reference does not on Mac OS X 10.7.4 and FreeBSD 9.0

Tags: c++, macos, boost, c++11, rvalue

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<size_t> v1, v2;
  v1.push_back(3);
  v1.push_back(4);
  v2 = static_cast<std::vector<size_t>&&>(v1);
  std::cout << v1.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << v2.size() << '\n';  
}
```

When I compiled the code on Linux using either GCC 4.7.0 or clang 3.1 with --std=c++0x, it output 0 and 2.
However, when I compiled the code on Mac OS X 10.7.4 or FreeBSD 9.0 using either clang 3.0 or clang 3.1 with --std=c++0x, it output 2 and 2. The GCC on my Mac OS X and FreeBSD is v4.2.1, which does not support --std=c++0x. So I used Boost.Move:

```
#include <boost/move/move.hpp>
v2 = boost::move(v1);
```

When I compiled the code on Mac OS X using GCC 4.2.1 with -I~/boost_1_49_0, it still output 2 and 2.

**Updated:** When I added --stdlib=libc++, the code output 0 and 2. The rvalue reference seemed working. However, when I changed the vector type from size_t to string, I got a compilation error, even though I commented the last three lines of code. This time the problem was not related to Rvalue reference but came from the push_back() function. When I removed --stdlib=libc++, it could pass compilation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v1, v2;
  v1.push_back("hello");
  /*
  v2 = static_cast<std::vector<std::string>&&>(v1);
  std::cout << v1.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << v2.size() << '\n';  
  */
}
```

which clang

```
/uac/gds/hjli/clang+llvm-3.1-x86_64-apple-darwin11/bin/clang
```

clang++ --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++ rval.cpp

```
In file included from rval.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1952:10: error: overload resolution selected
      implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator
    __r_ = _STD::move(__str.__r_);
         ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1942:9: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
        __move_assign(__str, true_type());
        ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1961:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::__move_assign' requested here
    __move_assign(__str, integral_constant<bool,
    ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1595:19: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=' requested here
        *__result = _STD::move(*__first);
                  ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1619:12: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'std::__1::__move<std::__1::basic_string<char> *,
      std::__1::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
    return _STD::__move(__unwrap_iter(__first), __unwrap_iter(__last),...
           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:153:14: note: expanded from macro '_STD'
#define _STD std::_LIBCPP_NAMESPACE
             ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__split_buffer:557:22: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'std::__1::move<std::__1::basic_string<char> *,
      std::__1::basic_string<char> *>' requested here
            __end_ = _STD::move(__begin_, __end_, __begin_ - __d);
                     ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:153:14: note: expanded from macro '_STD'
#define _STD std::_LIBCPP_NAMESPACE
             ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1289:13: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::__split_buffer<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > &>::push_back'
      requested here
        __v.push_back(_STD::move(__x));
            ^
rval.cpp:10:5: note: in instantiation of member function
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >::push_back' requested
      here
        v1.push_back("nice");
           ^
/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1941:5: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly
      deleted because '__compressed_pair<std::__1::basic_string<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__rep,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >' has a user-declared move constructor
    __compressed_pair(__compressed_pair&& __p)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You should use std::move to activate the move assignment operator.  ie `v2 = move(v1);`

Comment: The question is why doesn't boost::move(v1) move v1 into v2.

Comment: I think it's not worth fighting with incomplete/faulty implementations of the C++11 standard. Either install gcc 4.7.0 (or better) or wait until your OS has them.

Comment: @walter gcc 4.7 is incomplete, and I am sure it has a few bugs. But GCC has been supporting rvalue references for a while now.

Comment: Have you tried clang++ --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++

Comment: Adding --stdlib=libc++ outputs 0 and 2. Problem solved! Thanks.

Comment: Adding --stdlib=libc++ outputs 0 and 2. Problem seems solved. However, when I changed the vector type from size_t to string, I got another error.
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/usr/include/c++/v1/string:1952:10: error: overload resolution selected
      implicitly-deleted copy assignment operator
    __r_ = _STD::move(__str.__r_);

Comment: I think you're missing a word in title.

Comment: @juanchopanza of course is gcc 4.7.0 incomplete, but there is no point trying with something even more incomplete if one can use this instead. And it has bugs, just ran into one the other day.

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.2 is ancient, so its `std::vector` doesn't support rvalue references.  Using `boost::move` doesn't change that, it can't magically add rvalue reference support to a compiler + library that doesn't support it.  That means it does a *copy* not a move.

I suspect when you use Clang on your Mac it is using the old standard library from GCC 4.2, which *still* doesn't support rvalue references, even if the compiler does.  Can you use the libc++ library instead, which should be C++11-capable?

When you use Clang on Linux it uses the standard library from GCC 4.7, which does support C++11.

N.B. Clang 3.1 and GCC 4.7 both support `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x`, I think Clang 3.0 does too.  If all your compilers use the newer name for the option you might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
rvalue_reference boost::move(input_reference)
```

> This function provides a way to convert a reference into a rvalue reference in compilers with rvalue references. For other compilers converts `T&` into `::boost::rv<T>&` so that move emulation is activated.

If std::vector::operator=(boost::rv&) is not defined perhaps it is falling back to regular copy construction.  I think you have to do something special to have a class deal with boost::rvs